# Is there a way to use the orderBy() function from firestore using getDocs?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently trying to this (doesn't actually orderBy anything)

```
let articlesSnapshot = await getDocs(articlesRef, orderBy('timestamp'));
```

In the documentation they only show this use case using queries rather than getDocs...
Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to [create a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#web-version-9) like this:

```
let articlesSnapshot = await getDocs(query(articlesRef, orderBy('timestamp')));
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Just what I was looking for